# How to get IMPORTXML/IMPORTHTML result data in one cell?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, import

Working with Google Sheets, scraping from an html table like this:

[image]

I want to get all the rows in JUST ONE CELL...
like this:

[image]

And I couldn't get the way to do it!

The expected result is to get all the table data in an unique cell...
replacing columns division, just by a blank space
and converting rows to simple text lines.

Any help, please? =(

NOTE: First values not always include de ":" character. Number of rows in table may vary.

Comment: share your formula

Comment: Hi @player0. I have no formula... beyond a simple IMPORTHTML/IMPORTXML.- In fact, that's exactly what I'm asking for! hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Building from the previous answer you can try:**

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(importxml_formula),,9^9),CHAR(10)))),,9^9)
```

**Explaining the breakdown:**

```
QUERY(TRANSPOSE(importxml_formula),,9^9)
```

This returns a table with one row with the number of columns as rows in the original table, with the result of each column is the data of each row in the table.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(importxml_formula),,9^9),CHAR(10))
```

Each column will be appended with `CHAR(10)`, which corresponds to a line break.

```
TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(importxml_formula),,9^9),CHAR(10))))
```

Transpose the table into 1 column, x number of rows, and finally the last QUERY merges the column into a single cell.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

### Update:

Your IMPORTXML() already returned a single cell, and since they can be split by double space, you can use this formula instead:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(A1,B1),"  ",,FALSE)),CHAR(10))),,9^9)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Carlos M, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried but get same result... it gives me all the data in one cell... but no space between column values, and no line break between rows.- Its just all the values, following each other at the same cell - I have even  tried with a table of wikipedia, with same result  =(

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10cE9_-3nTMI9ZCSkGlEFgL2Oc1p_EOWrv_FGwPDLTN4/edit#gid=0

This is just a sample sheet where I'm trying to get it work

Comment: ````=IMPORTXML(A1,B1)```` already outputs a single cell.

Comment: You're right. Unlike IMPORTHTML, IMPORTXML returns the data in the same cell ... but without "space" between the values of different columns ... and neither, with a line break between the values of the different rows!  =(

Comment: Dear @Carlos M. Thank you very much!! By the way, if you look at the title of my post, I asked for both options: IMPORTXML/IMPORTHTML, since I could get the data with any of them... although, none in the way than I wanted, and I didn't know from which, it would be more appropriate to obtain the desired final result!
You answered me from the beginning, with an option based on IMPORTXML... and I only listened to your suggestion and work from there.
In fact, I just tried your previous suggestion, but changin IMPORTXML by IMPORTHTML... and it works great too!
Thank you SO MUCH for your help! =)

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 your_formula_here
 ),,9^9)), " ", "×"),,9^9), " ", CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)), "×", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Tried. I get a value that even i´ts not at the table:
#N/A  387420489

=(

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault ... a typo.
Yes, it returns the values of the table...
but it returns all merged in a single row... without any separator (space) between columns and not inserting any line break between rows

Comment: Sorry @player0, thank you very much! I have tried but get same result... it gives me all the data in one cell... but no space between column values, and no line break between rows.- Its just all the values, following each other at the same cell - I have even tried with a table of wikipedia, with same result =(